# My custom init shell script stops deployment script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, init

I have a deployment script which works fine. At the end of it I added this block:

```
cat << EOF > /etc/init.d/uwsgi
#!/bin/bash
daemon=$APPVENV/bin/uwsgi
args="--emperor $APPCONF/uwsgi/app.ini --daemonize /var/log/emperor.log --emperor-pidfile $APPDIR/emperor.pid --gid `id -g $APPUSER`"
pid=$APPDIR/emperor.pid
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting uwsgi"
        start-stop-daemon -p $pid --start --exec $daemon -- $args
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping script uwsgi"
        start-stop-daemon --signal INT -p $pid --stop $daemon -- $args
        ;;
    reload)
        echo "Reloading conf"
        kill -HUP $(cat $pid)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/uwsgi {start|stop|reload}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
EOF
```

Now when I run my deployment script it gets stuck here, and I just see a blinking cursor and it doesn't run any lines after it.

Have I done anything wrong with my formatting, as I know creating a file with cat was something very picky about how it was formatted, tabulated etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variables are still substituted in heredocs, also subshelling with $( ), which you do in your script here:

```
kill -HUP $(cat $pid)
```

your installer attempts to cat that file, with $pid probably empty, therefore it waits for input from standard input.
You want to escape those "$" to prevent expansion, like

```
\$(cat \$foo)
```

And of course with all those variables you don't want to get expanded during installation too.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. May you explain the first point please, what should I be doing with my vars?